Approximation of $\pi$ by integral and rational number
Via WolframAlpha, I observed that
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{4n}(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac\pi2-\frac pq \to 0$$
when the integer $n\to\infty$. This gives an approximation of $\pi$ by a rational number. It is not to difficult prove this approximation.
I wonder if these kind of integrals are used to prove the irrationality of $\pi$, etc.
Thanks for reading.

It is not $\approx$ but $=$. When $n$ is large, the bounds are $\frac{2 n-1}{32 n^3}$ and $\frac{1}{16 n^2}$

If you look at the indefinite integral, say for $n=3$ you see
$$\int\frac{x^{12} (1 - x^2)}{1 + x^2} dx = -x^{13/13} + (2 x^{11})/11 - (2 x^9)/9 + (2 x^7)/7 - (2 x^5)/5 + (2 x^3)/3 - 2 x + 2 \tan^{-1}(x) + constant$$
Your integral from $0$ to $1$ gives the first $2n+1$ terms of a famous approximation to $\pi$ except for a factor $2$ on the last term
$$\frac \pi 4 \approx 1-\frac 13+\frac 15-\frac 17+\frac 19 \ldots$$
This series converges only harmonically so is not useful for computation.
